# Is it possible to use SWT from Jython?

Tags: user-interface, swt, jython

The SWT-Gui looks very nice.
Is there an easy way to use it in Jython ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Given that you can use all Java classes from within Jython, it is also possible to use SWT.

For the example, adapted from an [SWT snippet](http://dev.eclipse.org/viewcvs/index.cgi/org.eclipse.swt.snippets/src/org/eclipse/swt/snippets/Snippet63.java?view=co), make sure you have the SWT jar on your CLASSPATH:

```
import org.eclipse.swt as swt
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets as widgets
import org.eclipse.swt.layout as layout

result = None

display = widgets.Display()

shell = widgets.Shell(display)
shell.pack()
shell.open()

dialog = widgets.Shell(shell, swt.SWT.DIALOG_TRIM | swt.SWT.APPLICATION_MODAL)
dialog.setLayout(layout.RowLayout())

ok = widgets.Button(dialog, swt.SWT.PUSH)
ok.setText ("OK")
cancel = widgets.Button(dialog, swt.SWT.PUSH);
cancel.setText("Cancel");

class MyListener(widgets.Listener):
    def handleEvent(self, event):
        global result
        result = event.widget == ok
        dialog.close()

listener = MyListener()
ok.addListener(swt.SWT.Selection, listener)
cancel.addListener(swt.SWT.Selection, listener)

dialog.pack()
dialog.open()
while not dialog.isDisposed():
    if not display.readAndDispatch():
        display.sleep ()
print "Result:", result
display.dispose()
```

Comment: Thank you Torsten, it looks very easy. (Sorry cannot upvote now)

Comment: Ah, it won't take long until you can do that.

Answer (score 9):

Jython has a few other niceties that makes the code cleaner.

Jython automagically translates getters & setters into public properties so that

```
ok.setText ("OK")
```

becomes simply

```
ok.text = 'OK'
```

You can then supply them as named arguments to the constructor. Jython also handles creating listener objects for your event handlers:

```
def handleEvent(self, event):
    global result
    result = event.widget == ok
    dialog.close()

ok = widgets.Button(dialog, swt.SWT.PUSH
        text='OK',
        widgetSelected=handleEvent)
cancel = widgets.Button(dialog, swt.SWT.PUSH
        text='Cancel',
        widgetSelected=handleEvent)
```

Comment: The "ok.text = 'Ok'" form is more idiomatic Jython (that is, it is more Pythonic -- it looks and feels more like Python code)

Answer (score 5):

Actually, there is no need for a special module. [This talk](http://seanmcgrath.pbwiki.com/f/BarCampDublinJythonPresentation.pdf) by Sean McGrath contains a simple example of a Jython/SWT GUI.

Slide 11 of the talk begins with:

```
"""
Simple SWT Example
Sean McGrath
"""
from org.eclipse.swt.events import *
from org.eclipse.swt.graphics import *
from org.eclipse.swt.layout import *
from org.eclipse.swt.widgets import *
from org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridData import *
from org.eclipse.swt import *
```

It shows that SWT is directly usable from Jython.
The [full example](http://seanmcgrath.pbwiki.com/f/swt.py) is right there at Sean's site.